# Play Framework app with SBT dependency on local Ivy repository crashes

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, akka

I have a Scala project that I want to use inside a Play Framework applicaiton.

I used publishLocal in SBT to publish the project to a local Ivy repository, as described here http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Publishing#publishing-locally

Then I created a new Play app and added the library dependency as described. I also added a resolver because Play couldn't find the correct location of Ivy

```
resolvers += Resolver.file("Local repo", file(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/.ivy2/local"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
```

When I start the app, I get a terrible long stack trace. I did not modify anything in the app, except for the build.sbt file.

Here is the stack trace.

```
scalax.io.ScalaIOException: MainException: class java.lang.NullPointerException(null)
---
class java.lang.NullPointerException(null)
     java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
     java.nio.channels.Channels$ReadableByteChannelImpl.read(Channels.java:385)
     scalax.io.ResourceAdapting$ReadableChannelAdapter.read(ResourceAdapting.scala:75)
     scalax.io.support.FileUtils$.copy(FileUtils.scala:130)
     scalax.io.traversable.Sliceable.toArray(Sliceable.scala:76)
     scalax.io.traversable.ByteResourceTraversable$$anonfun$toArray$2.apply(ByteResourceTraversable.scala:48)
     scalax.io.traversable.ByteResourceTraversable$$anonfun$toArray$2.apply(ByteResourceTraversable.scala:48)
     scalax.io.CloseableIterator$.liftedTree1$1(CloseableIterator.scala:122)
     scalax.io.CloseableIterator$.withIterator(CloseableIterator.scala:122)
     scalax.io.traversable.ByteResourceTraversable.toArray(ByteResourceTraversable.scala:48)
     scalax.io.Input$class.byteArray(Input.scala:81)
     scalax.io.managed.InputStreamResource.byteArray(InputStreamResource.scala:14)
     scalax.io.Input$class.string(Input.scala:136)
     scalax.io.managed.InputStreamResource.string(InputStreamResource.scala:14)
     play.api.i18n.Messages$MessagesParser.parse(Messages.scala:216)
     play.api.i18n.MessagesPlugin$$anonfun$play$api$i18n$MessagesPlugin$$loadMessages$1.apply(Messages.scala:286)
     play.api.i18n.MessagesPlugin$$anonfun$play$api$i18n$MessagesPlugin$$loadMessages$1.apply(Messages.scala:285)
     scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
     scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
     scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
     scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
     scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
     play.api.i18n.MessagesPlugin.play$api$i18n$MessagesPlugin$$loadMessages(Messages.scala:285)
     play.api.i18n.MessagesPlugin.messages$lzycompute(Messages.scala:296)
     play.api.i18n.MessagesPlugin.messages(Messages.scala:292)
     play.api.i18n.MessagesPlugin.onStart(Messages.scala:309)
     play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:88)
     play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:88)
     scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
     play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply$mcV$sp(Play.scala:88)
     play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:88)
     play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:88)
     play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:18)
     play.api.Play$.start(Play.scala:87)
     play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:139)
     play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:112)
     scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
     play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:112)
     play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:110)
     scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:200)
     play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:110)
     play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:102)
     scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
     scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
     scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1361)
     scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
     scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
     scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
     scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
     java.io.FilterInputStream.close(FilterInputStream.java:181)
     sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection$JarURLInputStream.close(JarURLConnection.java:108)
     java.nio.channels.Channels$ReadableByteChannelImpl.implCloseChannel(Channels.java:403)
     java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.close(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:115)
     scalax.io.ResourceAdapting$ReadableChannelAdapter.close(ResourceAdapting.scala:72)
     scalax.io.CloseableOpenedResource$$anonfun$closeAction$1.apply(Resource.scala:46)
     scalax.io.CloseableOpenedResource$$anonfun$closeAction$1.apply(Resource.scala:46)
     scalax.io.CloseAction$$anon$1.closeImpl(CloseAction.scala:20)
     scalax.io.CloseAction$$anon$1.closeImpl(CloseAction.scala:18)
     scalax.io.CloseAction$class.apply(CloseAction.scala:108)
     scalax.io.CloseAction$$anon$1.apply(CloseAction.scala:18)
     scalax.io.OpenedResource$class.close(Resource.scala:33)
     scalax.io.CloseableOpenedResource.close(Resource.scala:45)
     scalax.io.traversable.ReadableByteChannelIterator.doClose(ReadableByteChannelResourceTraversable.scala:64)
     scalax.io.CloseableIterator$class.close(CloseableIterator.scala:20)
     scalax.io.traversable.Sliceable.close(Sliceable.scala:17)
     scalax.io.CloseableIterator$.close$1(CloseableIterator.scala:106)
     scalax.io.CloseableIterator$.liftedTree1$1(CloseableIterator.scala:124)
     scalax.io.CloseableIterator$.withIterator(CloseableIterator.scala:122)
     scalax.io.traversable.ByteResourceTraversable.toArray(ByteResourceTraversable.scala:48)
     scalax.io.Input$class.byteArray(Input.scala:81)
     scalax.io.managed.InputStreamResource.byteArray(InputStreamResource.scala:14)
     scalax.io.Input$class.string(Input.scala:136)
     scalax.io.managed.InputStreamResource.string(InputStreamResource.scala:14)
     play.api.i18n.Messages$MessagesParser.parse(Messages.scala:216)
     play.api.i18n.MessagesPlugin$$anonfun$play$api$i18n$MessagesPlugin$$loadMessages$1.apply(Messages.scala:286)
     play.api.i18n.MessagesPlugin$$anonfun$play$api$i18n$MessagesPlugin$$loadMessages$1.apply(Messages.scala:285)
     scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
     scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
     scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
     scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
     scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
     play.api.i18n.MessagesPlugin.play$api$i18n$MessagesPlugin$$loadMessages(Messages.scala:285)
     play.api.i18n.MessagesPlugin.messages$lzycompute(Messages.scala:296)
     play.api.i18n.MessagesPlugin.messages(Messages.scala:292)
     play.api.i18n.MessagesPlugin.onStart(Messages.scala:309)
     play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:88)
     play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:88)
     scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
     play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply$mcV$sp(Play.scala:88)
     play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:88)
     play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:88)
     play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:18)
     play.api.Play$.start(Play.scala:87)
     play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:139)
     play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:112)
     scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
     play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:112)
     play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:110)
     scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:200)
     play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:110)
     play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:102)
     scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
     scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
     scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1361)
     scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
     scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
     scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
     scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

The Scala project that I publish to Local is using Akka 2.2.4, and I am using Play Framework 2.2.2

The Scala project compiles and tests without problems by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I solved this problem.

I had stupidly named one of the packages in my Scala project "messages", which caused a name conflict with something internal to Play Framework. I changed the package name and now it works.

Will now use proper package naming conventions.